# Differenciate 2 animations in AnimationListener

Tags: java, android, animation

I'd like to know how to differentiate two animations with the same duration in the AnimationListener. I know I can just declare:

```
animation1.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
```

And then I can do the same with animation 2 resulting in individual animation listeners, however I want something like this (not exactly because Animations do not have ID) *mind onAnimationEnd please*:

```
public class example implements Animation.AnimationListener{
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(detallesvis) {
        lldetalles.startAnimation(disappear);
    }
    else{
        finish();
    }
}

@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

}

@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    if (animation.getId()==animation1.getId())/* please note that animation.getId() function doesn't exist, it is just an example */ {
        dostuff();
    }
    if (animation.getId()==animation2.getId()){
    }
}

@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

}

}
```

I solved this problem by setting different durations to each animation and comparing animation.getduration()... however I'd like a cleaner approach (if it is possible).

Answer (score 1):

Equals Animation objects

```
@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    if (animation == animation1) {
        dostuff();
    }

    if (animation == animation2) {
    }
}
```